# Optimizing Neptune Bulk Load Jobs?

Tags: amazon-neptune

Currently we have an automation engine running to queue up billions of nodes/edges for our Neptune historical load.

The data pulls off Kafka and writes bulk CSVs into S3 to initiate the load. Currently I'm uploading files after each batch pulls a couple million records off the queue.

I'm using oversubscribe param and looked at the high-level docs for bulk optimizations. I'm seeing I can get about 36M records an hour, but looking to go faster. Do I want the output files to be larger? I can only run one job at a time and my queue is constantly filled up to the 65 cap limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, larger files should give better performance than smaller ones as the worker threads running the load will divide the file up amongst themselves. Larger instances also help the loads go faster. If possible, a db.r5.12xlarge is a good choice when you have a lot of data to load. You can scale it back down again once the volume of writes you need to achieve slows down and a smaller instance will suffice.